# How to batch delete events in Office365 using C# Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a method that deletes multiple events. Currently the code is as following:

```
    public async Task DeleteEvents(IEnumerable<string> eventExternalIds)
    {
        foreach(var eventExternalId in eventExternalIds)
        {
            await DeleteEvent(eventExternalId);
        }
    }

    public async Task DeleteEvent(string eventExternalId)
    {
        await GraphClient
            .Users[Username]
            .Calendars[CalendarName]
            .Events[eventExternalId]
            .Request()
            .DeleteAsync();
    }
```

I would imagine it won't perform well with any significant number of id's to delete. Is there a way to delete them all in a batch(es) instead of each individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### msgraph-sdk-dotnet v1.15.0 or above

For `msgraph-sdk-dotnet` version **`1.15.0` or above**  the support for Batch request has been introduced via [`BatchRequestContent` class](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-design/blob/master/content/BatchRequestContent.md)

Example

```
//1. construct a Batch request 
var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
var step = 1;
foreach (var eventId in eventIds)
{
     var requestUrl = graphClient
           .Me
           .Events[eventId]
           .Request().RequestUrl;

     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, requestUrl);
     var requestStep = new BatchRequestStep(step.ToString(), request, null);
     batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(requestStep);
     step++;
}


//2. Submit request
var batchRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch");
batchRequest.Content = batchRequestContent;
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(batchRequest);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var batchResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(batchRequest);
//3. Process response
var batchResponseContent = new BatchResponseContent(batchResponse);
var responses = await batchResponseContent.GetResponsesAsync();
foreach (var response in responses)
{
     if (response.Value.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         //...
     }                 
}
```

**Issues**

- while targeting `NetCore 2.1` or above or `.NET Framework`
  `NullReferenceException` exception might occur, to address this issue
  you could switch to [`1.16.0-preview.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Core/1.16.0-preview.1) ([details](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/470))

**Limitations**

> Note: A batch cannot hold more that 20 requests

### msgraph-sdk-dotnet v1.14.0 or older

For previous versions, the following example demonstrates how to implement a support for Batch request:

```
var batchRequest = new BatchRequest();
foreach (var eventId in eventIds)
{
   var request = graphClient.Me.Events[eventId].Request();
   batchRequest.AddQuery(request,HttpMethod.Delete);
}
var responses = await graphClient.SendBatchAsync(batchRequest);
```

where [`BatchRequest`](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/37dbe4762851decda79e32f5943b4fe3) is a custom class which adds support for [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)

Comment: If some of the requests in the batch fail, is there a way to find out the user ids that failed from the response? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922538/microsoft-graph-api-batch-request-doesnt-return-object-ids-that-failed?noredirect=1#comment130525522_73922538