# microsoft graph api batch request doesn't return object ids that failed

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to send a batch request to delete users from AAD group:

Sample Request:

> {Method: DELETE, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupId/members/UserId/$ref', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
> {
> }}

```
 private async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<RetryResponse>> SendBatch(BatchRequestContent tosend)
 {
       var response = await _graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(tosend);
       var responses = await response.GetResponsesAsync());
       foreach (var r in responses)
       {                
                using var res = r.Value;
                var status = res.StatusCode;
                var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       }
}
```

If the user is not found in the group, the ***content*** has the following value:

```
"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"Request_ResourceNotFound\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Resource '***groupId***' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"date\": \"2022-10-01T20:56:37\",\r\n      \"request-id\": \"fba27774-b542-4190-a6c8-83a857dcd7ec\",\r\n      \"client-request-id\": \"fba27774-b542-4190-a6c8-83a857dcd7ec\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

What I noticed is that the ***content*** includes the group object id NOT the user object id. Group exists in AAD. I confirmed the same. Let’s say I sent 10 users in the batch. 5 of them failed. Is there a way to get a list of user object ids (5 in this example) for which resource not found error occurred?

Comment: If the response doesn't contain it, how do you expect to get it?

Comment: As of now this feature not available, but if you want you can raise a feature request here : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform